# The argument type 'Future<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.dart

Tags: pdf, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here I have to use **pdfImageFromImageProvider** function to *stateless widget*. So, Is it possible to resolve this issue using stateless widget?

```
Future<Widget> getWidgetAsync(double size) async {
PdfImage val = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
  pdf: pdf.document,
  image: fw.AssetImage('assets/' + iconPath),
);

return Container(
  width: size,
  height: size,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: layoutbg,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: Image(val),
);
```

}

Comment: You can use a FutureBuilder to create your child https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Can we use FutureBuilder in Stateless widget?

Comment: Where do you call `getWidgetAsync` ?

Comment: Inside the container column.

Comment: return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        getWidgetAsync(20.0)
      ],
    );

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Try it.

Comment: It works in the normal stateless widget case but when using: 'package:printing/printing.dart' package  it won't work.

Comment: Can you share the error, I can't help you if you don't share more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must return `Future<Widget>`, as I'm understanding your question's title is your error, its mean that you returning a `Widget` not `Future<Widget>`. To do that, you should wrap your widget inside the Future like this:

```
Future<Widget> getWidgetAsync(double size) async {
PdfImage val = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
  pdf: pdf.document,
  image: fw.AssetImage('assets/' + iconPath),
);

return Future.value(Container(
  width: size,
  height: size,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: layoutbg,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: Image(val),
));
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Can you put the all error information under your question?

Comment: It works in the normal case of stateless widget when using the future builder.But, In my case I am using: 'package:printing/printing.dart' and  'package:pdf/widgets.dart';. And using this packages it is not possible to use FutureBuilder.